# Adding c++ functions to a C GUI

Tags: c++, c, function, user-interface, menu

i have created a c GUI using the following webpage:

http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/win32-apps-with-mingw/

it all works as expected however i am unsure how to import c++ functions from another source code and use them within the GUI.

i have a .c file called 'callbacks.c' that runs certain functions when a menu item in the GUI is clicked, e.g.

case ID_FILE_HEALTH:
        {
          //call 'add()' function from hello.cpp file
}

from that file (callbacks.c) you want to call a function called 'add()' from a file called hello.cpp when a certain case is hit. How do i run functions from another .cpp file inside this .c file.

does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:c] ?

Comment: You need to have a C API wrapper, unless you can compile your code along with the g++ compiler.

Comment: Sorry, im unsure on how i would use it, please could you explain?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call C++ functions from C you need to give them C linkage with

```
extern "C" {
// here you can include your C++ header with C API
}
```

By C API added to your C++ content I mean addition of functions with C prototypes doing their job using your C++ content. For example:

car.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
// C API
struct car;
struct car* new_car(double f_prospect, double f_real);
void delete_car(struct car* d);
int car_f(struct car* c);
void car_add(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

car.cpp

```
#include "car.h"

#include <iostream>
struct car {};
class Car : public struct car {
  public:
      ~Car();
      Car(double f_prospect, double f_real) : 
          fuel_consumption_as_in_ad_prospect(f_prospect), real_fuel_consumption(f_real);
      int f(void);
      double fuel_consumption_as_in_ad_prospect;
  private:
      double real_fuel_consumption;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, still slightly unsure i have edited the post would you be able to explain with regards to the additional post.

Comment: as in example, declare an interface to your function with extern "C", include that interface in C file and link to C++ code

Comment: I'm sorry I'm really new to programming in C++ could you please explain in more detail, thanks so much